# Unit test of Retrofit and RxJava never finishes if HttpException occurs

Tags: android, junit, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to implement unit test (`JUnit`) that tests `Retrofit` `Observable` in case when web server returns `422 Unprocessable entity`.

I have the following API service (which I create using `retrofit.create(AccountService.class)`):

```
public interface AccountService {
   @POST("users")
   Observable<User> createNewUser(@Body User user, @Query("v_uuid") String vUuid, @Query("v_code") String vCode);
}
```

And I call this service from unit test:

```
Observable<User> observable = accountService
        .createNewUser(newUser, "uuid", "code")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Also I use `TestSubscriber<User>` in order to assert my Observable:

```
TestSubscriber<User> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>(); 

observable
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(testSubscriber);

testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
// assert testSubscriber.getOnErrorEvents()
```

I use `SchedulersHook` (via JUnit `@Rule`) as it has been described in the following blog post: http://alexismas.com/blog/2015/05/20/unit-testing-rxjava/. I use `Schedulers.immediate()` as a substitution for the following schedulers:

- `Schedulers.io()`
- `Schedulers.computation()`
- `Schedulers.newThread()`
- `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

But it seems that test will never finish. It hangs when I call `observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(testSubscriber);`.
At the same time this code works well if web server responds with `2xx codes`. Also if I remove my custom `SchedulersHook` from the code, it become working even if server responds with `4xx codes`.

Additional info: I use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver%20MockWebServer) in order to emulate the web server and I see from logs that `Retrofit` sends the request to the server.
My `Gradle` dependencies look as follows:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1-SNAPSHOT'
testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.1.2'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
```

**UPDATE:**
After digging into `rxjava` I found that using `merge` operator and different `Schedulers` (particularly, substituting them using `SchedulersHook`) leads to the infinite `sleeps()` somewhere inside `OperatorMerge.InnerSubscriber<T>`.

Comment: It's quite unclear what do you want to test. How `RxJava` core methods works(`observeOn`, `subscribe`)? I bet they work ok. Or you simplified your example and you have some `flatMap` or `map` operators usage in your test?

Comment: @foxinsocks, I'm a beginner with `rxjava` and `retrofit`. And I'd like to research how this stuff works. At this moment I don't have others operators and I just want to see how `Retrofit` `HttpException` is propagated into my `Subscriber` (currently `TestSubscriber`). But I think they (other operators) will appear in the further code. At any rate, do additional operators will affect this behavior?

Comment: Yes, `operators` affect streams and exceptions propagation. There is nothing to figure out because everything is pretty straightforward for any `Observable`: all `errors`/`exceptions` go into `onError` handler of your `subscriber`. Inside `onError` handler you can cast `Throwable` to `RetrofitError` and get status code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problems is that `Subscriber.onError()` isn't called because `subscribe()` doesn't finish. I figured out that behavior I faced appears when calling the combining functions (`merge`, `zip`, etc) and manipulating `Schedulers` (calling the `observeOn`/`subscribeOn` or using `SchedulersHook`).

Comment: @ipertsev do you have a sample? I am trying to do something similar as well.

Comment: @SoH, what kind of sample to you need? do you need a sample of working unit test with RxJava?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the reason code never finishes. Thanks to Dávid Karnok from the community (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/2rOHj1mvShk):

> What happens is that the RxRingBuffer's cleanup thread sleeps on the immediate scheduler, preventing any progress for other components.
>
> There is a fundamental problem with immediate scheduler; it is not a real scheduler and due to its sleeping nature, it can cause unexpected hangs.
>
> For testing operators, it is much better to use TestScheduler directly and avoid the use of RxJavaPlugins as much as possible.

After I had switched to `TestScheduler` everything began work as expected.

It's  also recommended to use dependency injection (`Dagger 2`) in order to manage the `Schedulers`.